# how to read an array value from another array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Is there a method to read an array from another?

this is my 2 array,

```
$productArr = [
    "PT" => [
        "cat" => [ "image" => "cat.jpg", "desc" => "blah blah"],
        "fish"=> [ "image" => "fish.jpg", "desc" => "blah blah"],
        "dog" => [ "image" => "dog.jpg","desc" => "blah blah"],
    ],
    "KC" => [
        "Ice" => [ "image" =>   "ice.jpg", "desc" => "mah mah mah"],
        "cold"=> [ "image" => "cold.jpg", "desc" => "mah mah mah"],
        "water"=> [ "image" =>   "water.jpg", "desc" => "mah mah mah"],
    ],

];

$featuredArr = [
    "KC" => "Ice",
    "PT" => "cat",
];
```

For example, from `$featuredArr`, "Ice" will link with `$productArr` "Ice", to produce the "desc" and "image".

Comment: just use that value as keys, they exists on the other anyway, just add an isset or array key exists if you want some checking, check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$code = "KC";
$product = $productArr[$code][$featuredArr[$code]];
echo $product['image'];
echo $product['desc'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach($featuredArr as $key=>$val)
    if($productArr[$key][$val])
        print_r($productArr[$key][$val]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$productArr = [
    "PT" => [
        "cat" => [ "image" => "cat.jpg", "desc" => "blah blah"],
        "fish"=> [ "image" => "fish.jpg", "desc" => "blah blah"],
        "dog" => [ "image" => "dog.jpg","desc" => "blah blah"],
    ],
    "KC" => [
        "Ice" => [ "image" =>   "ice.jpg", "desc" => "mah mah mah"],
        "cold"=> [ "image" => "cold.jpg", "desc" => "mah mah mah"],
        "water"=> [ "image" =>   "water.jpg", "desc" => "mah mah mah"],
    ],

];

$featuredArr = [
    "KC" => "Ice",
    "PT" => "cat",
];

foreach ($featuredArr as $key => $value) {
   if ($productArr[$key][$value]) {
      echo "key $key=>$value exists:  <br />";
      foreach ($productArr[$key][$value] as $newKey => $newValue) {
         echo "$newKey :: $newValue <br />";
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
key KC=>Ice exists:  <br />image :: ice.jpg <br />desc :: mah mah mah <br />key PT=>cat exists:  <br />image :: cat.jpg <br />desc :: blah blah <br />
```

Please note that it largely depends on what use you have to do of your keys and your values: using the above code you can dinamically loop through your array by adding the desired key=>value pair to your $featuredArr array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am having a problem echoing out the image, do you have a solution to that?

Comment: What kind of problem? Echoing the image or displaying it correctly? be sure to check the exact path of the image when you print the tag.